# Provide WebMethod action dynamically for CXF autogenerated webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm autogenerating soap webservice classes with `CXF`. The result will contain the hardcoded URL that is found in the `WSDL/XSD` files.

```
@WebService(...)
@XmlSeeAlso(...)
@SOAPBinding(...)
public interface AutoGeneratedPortType {

    @WebResult(...)
    @WebMethod(action = "http://localhost:8080/TheService") //that's the problem
    public MyRsp service(
        @WebParam(...)
        MyReq parameters
    ) throws FaultMessage;
}
```

Thus, I first have to go through all `WSDL` files and replace the localhosts with the productive `URL` (which works fine with Notepad++ over all files, but is still work to do).
Problem: every time the API that I'm getting the WSDLs of is providing updated files, I have to repeat these steps.

I'd prefer to somehow "override" the webmethod action parameter when calling the service methods:

```
AutoGeneratedPortType port = new MyService().geAutoGeneratedPort();
port.service(req);
```

But it this possible? Can I provide the generated `@WebMethod` URL dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody knows a better solution, here is one possibility:

```
Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
rc.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, ENDPOINT);
```

Comment: If you are using cxf maven code gen plugin `cxf-codegen-plugin` you can specify wsdl location using following configuration `<wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/kp.wsdl</wsdlLocation>` Here I configure for classpath for wsdlLocations. This may be bit irrelevant but you can try something like this. But I have not seen action beinng configured the way you did.

Comment: I do configure the wsdl location with maven already. Please note that I asked to specify the enpoint because all the wsdl I'm getting provided contains localhost as URL!